# What should I use for speech recognition?

Tags: software

I was wondering, my team and me are working on a robot communication-oriented and we wanted to add speech recognition on it.

What technology should I use ?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question, as speech recognition can go in some implementations, like: you need to accept non-trained commands? you need to accept no trained voices? you need to distinguish between voices? If you can train, you can use a "matching" algorithm with the recorded commands, if not (that is, anyone should be recognized by the system) that is a complex system, and major is closed source.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any "must" for you task. In turn, it depends on what your robot platform is. In the context of embedded systems, MATLAB could be cumbersome.

I don't know what your robot system is like, but maybe this [article](http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0022/) based on ROS and Sphinx is a good starting point?

Also, for the purpose of understanding speech recognition technologies, the [HTK toolkit](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/) and the [HTK book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTK_%28software%29) are a good reference.

For a general idea of the state-of-art research on speech recognition, you can also visit http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/rwth-asr/

Comment: I'll try it asap.
Thx !

Answer (score 2):

You must go through softwares like matlab(licensed). Open source versions are also available like QtOctave and FreeMat.

You must have a sound knowledge about Digital Signal Procesing , different type of Filters etc..

Comment: Why is matlab better for embedded ?
Why not sphinx ? why not SmartVR ?

Comment: @DavidBensoussan I don't think it is :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find the Natural Language Tool Kit useful.

http://nltk.org/

Comment: On my "to try" list ! Thx